# How to fix error 'too many arguments for function-like macro invocation 'TEXT'' in c++ UE4

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I am trying to print a message containing an objects name that the compiler will find. I am getting an error saying I have to many argument for function like macro invocation. I am going off a turorial on udemy here is a link to the video: https://www.udemy.com/unrealcourse/learn/v4/t/lecture/4590240?start=0.

I have tried this code:

```
#include "PositionReport.h"
#include "Gameframework/Actor.h"

UPositionReport::UPositionReport()
{

    PrimaryComponentTick.bCanEverTick = true;


}



void UPositionReport::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();


    FString ObjectName = GetOwner()->GetName();
    //The error is right here
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Position report for %s!", *ObjectName));

}
void UPositionReport::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);


}
```

Is there a solution to stop this error from occurring?

Comment: You didn't provide any info about your build environment, but my gut thinks you are compiling for Windows, and `TEXT()` is resolving to Microsoft's [`TEXT` macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text), which has only 1 input parameter.

Comment: IDK but `UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Position report for %s!"), *ObjectName);` seems like a thing to try.

Comment: Sorry I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Thank you John this actually worked.

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong. You are passing two parameters to the `TEXt` macro, but it accepts only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable arguments need to be outside the TEXT() macro's parens, like so:

```
UE_LOG(LogTemp, Log, TEXT("Pathname: %s"), *UnrealPath);
```